# Itunes app interruption by my be avoided? Can music continue to play despite my app running?

Tags: iphone, ios

Itunes app interruption by my be avoided? Can music continue to play despite my app running? I built an app using the media player framework, is it possible for the intunes app to play music in the background during the same instance that my app (movieclip) is running. My movie clip contains no audio. What type of AVframework do I need to use in order to allow the itunesapp to continue background playback during my app session?

Answer (score 0):

With AVAudioSession and some code from 71 squared's sound manager:

```
- (BOOL)isExternalAudioPlaying {
    UInt32 audioPlaying = 0;
    UInt32 audioPlayingSize = sizeof(audioPlaying);
    AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying, &audioPlayingSize, &audioPlaying);
    return (BOOL)audioPlaying;
}

if (!isExternalAudioPlaying) {
        soundCategory = AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient;
        audioSessionError = nil;
        [audioSession setCategory:soundCategory error:&audioSessionError];
        if (audioSessionError)
            NSLog(@"WARNING - SoundManager: Error setting the sound category to SoloAmbientSound")
}
```

If you use an audio session and set its category to AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient, it should continue to play the ipod library's music when you start the app.